# How can I use mockito to verify that a function has never been called, with any argument?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, mocking

I want to verify that a function has never been called using mockito. I am aware of the `verifyNever` function, but that does not seem to work in my case, or I'm not using it correctly.

My test currently looks like this:

```dart
test('when the string is less than 3 characters api is not called', () async {
  var databaseService = getAndRegisterDatabaseService();
  var model = ViewModel();

  model.searchPatient('sk');

  // Wait for futures to finish.
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0));

  verifyNever(databaseService.searchPatient('sk'));
});
```

but I get an error when running the test:

```dart
No matching calls (actually, no calls at all).
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
```

To me it seems like `verifyNever` won't work if the function has *never* been called, just that it has never been called with a specific argument. Is that correct? In that case, is there another way to test what I want?

Comment: I don't know where your error is coming from; I can't reproduce it using `verifyNever`.  If my answer doesn't help you, I suggest providing a minimal, complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out the problem was as simple as me reading the output from the test wrong... You can see my answer below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After trying to write a minimal reproducible example it turns out that the problem was that I read the output incorrectly.

In the following output I read the top row as the title for the failed test, when in fact it is the bottom row that is the name of the failed error than corresponds to the above output.

```dart
✓ ViewmodelTest - searchPatient - when the string is less than 3 characters api is not called
No matching calls (actually, no calls at all).
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
package:test_api                                     fail
_VerifyCall._checkWith
package:mockito/src/mock.dart:672
_makeVerify.<fn>
package:mockito/src/mock.dart:954
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
test/viewmodel_tests/viewmodel_test.dart:144
✖ ViewmodelTest - searchPatient - api is called with correct and cleaned query
```

Answer (score 2):

[The `verifyNever` examples](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#verifying-exact-number-of-invocations--at-least-x--never) from `package:mockito`'s `README.md` cover your case:

> ```dart
> // Or never called
> verifyNever(cat.eatFood(any));
> ```

So, in your case, assuming that `databaseService` is a `Mock` object, you should be able to use `verifyNever(databaseService.searchPatient(any));` to verify that the `.searchPatient` method is never called, regardless of the arguments.